# Geting exception while using DistributedCache in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, distributed-cache

I have used below mentioned code for Distributed Caching in main class.

```
job.addCacheFile(new URI(args[2]));
```

Below mentioned code is in reduce class.

```
@Override
        protected void setup(Reducer<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            super.setup(context);
            URI[] paths = context.getCacheFiles();
            if (paths.length > 0) {
                loadDeliveryStatusCodes(paths[0].toString());
            }
        }
        private void loadDeliveryStatusCodes(String file) {
            String strRead;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./some"));
                while ((strRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String splitarray[] = strRead.split(",");
                    deliveryCodesMap.put(splitarray[0].trim(), splitarray[1].trim());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

I am getting below mentioned exception.

```
@@@@@@@@/user/DeliveryStatusCodes.txt 1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./some (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at com.hadoop.intellipaat.UserSMSDeliveryJob$USERNameSMSStatusCodeMapper.loadDeliveryStatusCodes(UserSMSDeliveryJob.java:95)
```

Your help will save my day.
Thanks.

Comment: What is `args[2]`?

Comment: It is txt file location in hadoop directory which I want to use as cache. eg. /user/DeliveryStatusCodes.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the `#some` from end of your `args[2]`.At the moment you have `/user/DeliveryStatusCodes.txt`, but you should have

```
/user/DeliveryStatusCodes.txt#some
```

Without it, `FileReader` is literally looking for `./some`, which of course won't exist.

Or you can skip the alias (it's optional) and write

```
new FileReader("/user/DeliveryStatusCodes.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. I tried this before but somehow it was not working that time, now it's working.

I m also facing some issue with reducer. It is not combining mappers output.

https://github.com/ragnar-lothbrok/hadoop-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/hadoop/intellipaat/UserSMSDeliveryJob.java

In reducer [key,[value1,value1]] [key,[valeu2,value2]] but it should be like this [key,[value1,value2]]. Could you please help me.

Comment: Are you sure the Reducer is running? Are you seeing your sysout?

Comment: Yes I did debug and use sysout also. Control is coming over there.

123 456########[user-sms~001, user-sms~001]

456 123########[user~Tom, user~Tom] 

789 123########[user-sms~003, user-sms~003]